# rspec rails : unit test database query

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, unit-testing, rspec

I have user model, query helper and a controller : the helper contain a method that return a list  of user when send a search query request from the view:

```
class UserQueryHelper

  def initialize( query = nil )
    @query = Arel.sql("UNACCENT('%#{ query }%')")
  end

  def search
    User.where( first_name.matches( @query ).or( last_name.matches( @query ) ))
  end

protected

  def users   ; User.arel_table   ; end

  def first_name
    Arel::Nodes::NamedFunction.new( "UNACCENT", [ users[ :first_name ] ] )
  end

  def last_name
    Arel::Nodes::NamedFunction.new( "UNACCENT", [ users[ :last_name ] ] )
  end

end
```

in the model I call that helper  :

```
def self.search( query )
    if query.present?
      UserQueryHelper.new( query ).search
    else
      all
    end
end
```

and in the controller I get the list of user searched by the admin :

```
users_to_export = User.regular.search(params[:search]).includes( :company )
```

I want to write some unit test for this and I didn't got the right way to do it and I tried this code but it doesn't work :

```
  require 'spec_helper'

describe UserQueryHelper do

  let!( :query ) { UserQueryHelper.new( "sahnoun" ) }
  it "return user" do
    user1 = create :user, first_name: "sahnoun", last_name: "mabrouk", company: $company
    expect( query.send( :search ) ).to include user1

  end

end
```

Comment: Are you testing the search method or the initialize method? shouldn't you have separate tests for each of them?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You must be getting an error `stack level too deep`

```
let!( :query ) { UserQueryHelper.new( query ) }
```

is executing as

```
UserQueryHelper.new( UserQueryHelper.new (UserQueryHelper.new (....)))
```

it should be defined as

```
let!( :query ) { UserQueryHelper.new( "<Your Test Query>" ) }
```

Comment: Thanks ayush for your comment , yes that's exactly the error i got, so in "<Your Test Query>" should i write a query like : "User.where( first_name.matches( user1.first_name ).or( last_name.matches( user1.last_name ) ))" ?

Comment: @noun7 probably not because it should be pure SQL, but consider this could be dangerous if the query can be constructed by a user.

Comment: you can try UserQueryHelper.new( "sahnoun" ) since you are later creating a test user with this name (sahnoun). Your test will pass.

Comment: I did like you said but it didn't pass !

Comment: send me the output  `puts query.send( :search )`

Comment: check if User is getting created or not?  puts user1

Comment: it's not created : nil :/

Comment: you will have to check why its not getting created, it should not be nil anyway, put debugger after `user1 = create :user, first_name: "sahnoun", last_name: "mabrouk"` and check user1.

Comment: it's created and the test pass ok , I'll update my answer ! thx again

Comment: @noun7  congrats. Also upvote the answer if it was helpful :)